# Do not ask login for rememberMe users in checkout process etc. in SAP Hybris

Tags: spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, remember-me

When I make `rememberMe`(spring security) active in Hybris, I want `rememberMe` users to behave like Hard Login users. I mean, I would like those rememberMe users (soft login) to not face any obstacle like when they want to proceed in the checkout process or something like that. How can I achieve this in SAP Hybris platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your question: How to disable HardLogin for the remember-me user in Hybris?

find the detail explanation [here](https://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-enable-remember-me-functionality.html)

**Change `RequireHardLoginBeforeControllerHandler`**

Change `beforeController` method of `RequireHardLoginBeforeControllerHandler.java`, so that it always check if `remember-me` cookies present in the request and `guid` is missing or invalidated then create new `guid` without redirecting login page.

Below **`yourstorefrontRememberMe`** needs to change with your storefront name, like `mySiteRemmberMe`

```
    public static final String SECURE_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIES = "yourstorefrontRememberMe";

    @Resource(name = "guidCookieStrategy")
    private GUIDCookieStrategy guidCookieStrategy;

    @Override
    public boolean beforeController(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final HandlerMethod handler) throws Exception
    {
        boolean redirect = true;

        // We only care if the request is secure
        if (request.isSecure())
        {
            // Check if the handler has our annotation
            final RequireHardLogIn annotation = findAnnotation(handler, RequireHardLogIn.class);
            if (annotation != null)
            {
                final String guid = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(SECURE_GUID_SESSION_KEY);

                if ((!getUserService().isAnonymousUser(getUserService().getCurrentUser()) || checkForAnonymousCheckout()) &&
                        checkForGUIDCookie(request, response, guid))
                {
                    redirect = false;
                }

                if (redirect)
                {
                    if(isRememberMeCookiePresent(request))
                    {
                        // If you find your guid is missing, lets recreate it.
                        guidCookieStrategy.setCookie(request, response);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LOG.warn((guid == null ? "missing secure token in session" : "no matching guid cookie") + ", redirecting");
                        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, getRedirectUrl(request));
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    protected boolean isRememberMeCookiePresent(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

      if ((cookies == null) || (cookies.length == 0)) {
          return false;
      }

      for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
          if (SECURE_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIES.equals(cookie.getName())) {
              return cookie.getValue() != null;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried second step with some minor differences before you replied to me.It worked but this prevented all RequireHardLogIn actions everywhere. I just wonder whether it is possible to disable RequireHardLogIn for "remember-me" specific.That is, is it possible to perform disabling RequireHardLogIn just for remember-me user?

Comment: What I interpreted was, you want to disable HardLogin at all. Anyway, let me update my answer with `remember me` cookie check to bypass only those users. Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/enable-remember-me-in-hybris.html